# Triggering a JQuery keydown event with no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

I'm having trouble triggering a keydown event for a particular letter. I've searched and still haven't found anything that's been helpful for the issue I'm having, wondering if anyone can help me out. I've set an alert to test it out of which I don't receive either. I read that event.which is helpful in this case but not sure where to put, when I tried it out it didn't work. The purpose of this it to animate an alternative .gif when this key is pressed.

```
$('target-class').keydown(function(event) {
    if ($(this).event.keyCode == 85) {
        alert('Press this key');
    }
//here are my <script> tags in html //
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(this).event.keyCode == 85` is wrong, just `event.keyCode == 85` is enough!

Comment: If you have a `<div>` with class name `target-class` you need a dot, like so: `$('.target-class')` and you do not have closing brackets for the keydown function `});`

Comment: What type of element has the `target-class` (`<input />`, `<div />`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Keyboard js](http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/)

I have used it and it's awesome if you need to bind your whole keyboard.